# Limit of integral of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C$ be a semi-circle of center $O=(0,0)$ and radius $R$, $y\geq 0$ , find the limit as $R$ tends to infinity of :
$\int_C e^{iz}/z^2 dz $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude of the integral can be bounded by $\pi/R$, so the limit is zero.

**Addendum (details):** Parameterize the contour as $z=Re^{it}$ ($0\leq t\leq\pi$). Then we have
$$z = Re^{it}$$
$$dz = iRe^{it}\;dt$$
$$z^2 = R^2e^{2it}$$
$$e^{iz}=e^{iRe^{it}}=e^{iR\cos t - R\sin t}$$
so the integral can be writen as
$$I(R) = \int_{t=0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{iR\cos t}e^{-R\sin t}iRe^{it}}{R^2e^{2it}}dt$$
$$=\int_{t=0}^{\pi}\left(ie^{i(R\cos t -t)}\right)\left(\frac{e^{-R\sin t}}{R}\right)\;dt$$

The first factor of the integrand has magnitude $1$, and the numerator of the second factor of the integrand is at most $1$. Since the interval of integration has length $\pi$, we have that

$$|I(R)|\leq \pi\cdot\frac{1}{R} = \frac{\pi}{R}$$
Thus $$\lim_{R\to\infty}I(R) = 0$$

Comment: More details please :)

Comment: @MalakDiab: Added in answer.